# Draw line on last record of each report page

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I got a problem with a report.
I will draw a line on the last record's page like in the example below.
In the report I have:

- Header section (with the company info)
- Page header section (with the titles column)
- Detail section (for each record)
- Page footer (for the page number)
- Report footer (totals about the report)

I need this "break" line because I put some lines in the detail section for have a table like report.

```
Page1:
 _______________________
|     Report Header     |
|       Goes Here       |
|-----------------------|
|     Page Header       |
|-----------------------|
| Record1               |
|                       |
| Record2               |
|                       |
| Record3               |
|                       |
| Record4               |
|                       |
| Record5               |
|                       |
| Record6               |
|-----------------------| <- Line
|                       |
|                       |
|     Page Footer       |
|_______________________|


Page2:
 _______________________
|-----------------------|
|     Page Header       |
|-----------------------|
| Record7               |
|                       |
| Record8               |
|                       |
| Record9               |
|                       |
| Record10              |
|                       |
| Record11              |
|                       |
| Record12              |
|                       |
| Record13              |
|                       |
| Record14              |
|-----------------------| <- Line
|     Page Footer       |
|_______________________|


Page3:
 _______________________
|-----------------------|
|     Page Header       |
|-----------------------|
| Record15              |
|                       |
| Record16              |
|-----------------------| <- Line
|                       |
|    Report footer      |
|                       |
| Info1                 |
| Info2                 |
| Info3                 |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|     Page Footer       |
|_______________________|
```

I tried to add some textboxes in the report's detail section with the running sum but I can't figure out how to know it's the last record.
Somebody can help me? Thank you

Comment: So you want to show the line only when you are in last record?  Or you want the line for every last record in every page?

Comment: I want show the line on the last record on every page, sorry for the bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is no need for VBA. Just try to detect wich section of the report shows what you want to do. Detail section won't work because it shows for every record.so step up 1 level. According to your info, You have no grouped your data in any way, so, I would bet for Page Footer. Draw a line there, then go to Preliminar View, and check it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried to draw the lilne in the page footer but it is too far from the last record printed on the page, it keep a white gap beetween them, I will put the line in the detail section for print the report more "table" like possibile. Or maybe it's possibile close the gap?

Comment: The gap you say is determined by the height of the detail section. Try making it shorter

Comment: I cut the detail section short as possibile but in the page with less record (like page 3) the break line it will be on the bottom's page just near the page's number. Your solution work well if the page is full of record, but in my case sometimes I have few record than full page.

Comment: Then I'm afraid ou will need to groupe your data so you will have optional headers and footers, and use those instead of Page Footer.